# Область отображения в Webbrowser

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Как в *delphi* задать область веб-страницы, которая мне необходима. Чтобы при старте она отображалась.

К примеру: если у меня длинная  веб-страница, при старте оно всегда отображает верхнюю часть страницы, а как задать участок, который мне необходим для отображения?

Answer (score 2):

Вставить в нужном месте страницы закладку, например:

```
<h2 id="updates">Новости обновлений!</h2>
```

а потом загружать эту страницу по ссылке с указанием нужного места:

> http://www.company.ru/news.html#updates

Работает это [примерно так](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).